# Authorize.Net SDK for Dotnet Core

Tags: authorize.net

The only SDK that I was able to find in their development site was not for dotnetCore. Does anyone know if there is an SDK for dotnetCore?

Their support is sending me to stackoverflow and I could not find an answer on the development community forum